# NSScrollview items not displaying properly when scrolling

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm currently using a NSScrollView and when I'm scrolling the button inside of it gets redisplay under it. How can I fix this.

Here's a display of the problem: [image]

```
int x = 00; //position x
    int y = 00; //pssition y

    int width = 100;
    int height = 40;

    NSButton* a = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(x, y, width, height)];
    a.title = @"Scene";
    //[a setButtonType:<#(NSButtonType)#>]; //Set what type button You want
    [a setBezelStyle:NSSquareLineCapStyle]; //Set what style You want

    [self.box addSubview:a];
```

Now, I know the button gets displayed properly, it looks like when I'm scrolling, it is getting redrawn. I don't want the bottom under the first one to be shown at all.

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off on this, but it could go along with a line of code I have from a tutorial i did. A Pong game. So that the ball would be redrawn on the screen as it moved around. the line was:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(gameLoop) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
```

Hopefully This helped! If not hopefully it gave you some more ideas?